# Should I use Facelets "jsfc" attribute?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

Facelets uses the **jsfc** attribute to convert HTML elements to their associated **JSF** components. This is rather helpful for fast prototyping as it allows you to create your views using a visual design tool. However I recently discovered [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/12/18/baby-steps-jsf-2) blog post by *Cay Horstmann* where he lays waste to the use of **jsfc** together with complex components such as **h:dataTable**.

This alarmed me as *Cay Horstmann* is the author of multiple of my favorite Java books. However my Google-fu skills have yielded zero results when trying to determine the scope/nature of the problem, other than a recent post by [Ed Burns](http://www.coderanch.com/t/481245/JSF/java/Ed-Chris-jsfc-JSF-version), who seams to like **jsfc** (and he is after all the co-spec lead for **JSF**). So my question is simply, is it recommended to use **jsfc** with Facelets ? and if not what's the problem it introduces.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As you said, the `jsfc` attribute is essentially usefull when you have to "convert" an HTML prototype to a JSF page. For example, when you have an HTML input text:

```
<input type="text" .../>
```

you can add the `jsfc` attribute in order to convert this HTML component into a JSF component:

```
<input type="text" jsfc="h:inputText" .../>
```

This is equivalent to writing the following JSF code:

```
<h:inputText .../>
```

As stated in the Facelets documentation [here](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template-remove) or [here](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template-repeat), the attribute `jsfc` can also be used to "map" Facelets components. For example, you can remove a part of the HTML code:

```
<span jsfc="ui:remove">
This won't be compiled either <h:outputText value="#{foo.bar}"/>
</span>
```

You can also create a table using this attribute:

```
<table>
    <tr jsfc="ui:repeat" value="#{dept.employees}" var="emp" class="#{emp.manager ? 'mngr' : 'peon'}">
       <td>#{emp.lastName}</td>
       <td>#{emp.firstName}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this example, we do not link this table to a `h:datatable` component, but we create a table with HTML code, using the JSF component `ui:repeat` to iterate on rows.

As you can see, the `jsfc` attribute can be used to convert one HTML component into one JSF component in a JSF page. So for complex components, such as the datatable, you will have to use some workarounds (using `ui:repeat` instead of the `h:datatable` component).

Another point is that you will not be able to use third-libraries components such as the ones proposed by RichFaces, IceFaces, Tomahawk, and so on. And these libraries are really one of the interests of JSF.

So to summarize: `jsfc` can be usefull to transform a HTML prototype into a JSF applications, essentially for creating Proof of Concepts or designing the general UI. However, I think it is better to avoid this component once the "real" development starts...

Comment: Well... actually, I've just tested the jsfc attribute with a third-party component, and it worked okay...