# How to make facelets conform to XHTML 1.0 Transitional?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, facelets, standards-compliance

Why can't facelets XHTML files be valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional files?
If I submit a facelet file in an xml validator (e.g. w3c validator) it shows an error on the first tag defined in one of the taglibs.

Example 1:

If I submit the following file to the validator, it shows no error, validation goes fine because no taglib tags appear in the document (one jsf taglib is defined though).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Example 2:

Now I just inserted the h:head and h:body tags from the xmlns:h namespace but this causes errors in the validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
<title></title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Certainly I'm missing something fundamental here, but I still can't figure out what.

This is my first question here at S.O. so please point out any errors, thank you!

Comment: The second example is obtained after rendering?

Comment: No, it isn't. I just manually wrote in the Direct Input tab of the W3C Validator - http://validator.w3.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [Lifecycle of a Facelets Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giprr.html) you can see that your view is rendered to the client. This will transform tags like `<h:head>` replacing them with their xhtml equivalent e.g. `<head>`. If you want templates that are XHTML valid you may want to try with the jsfc attribute but it has its [drawbacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337908/should-i-use-facelets-jsfc-attribute)

Comment: Yes I expected that was something so obvious. Guess I've got to read more on the lifecycle. Thanks for the link! :)