# programmatically created jsf components disappear on refresh

Tags: jsf, primefaces

An outputpanel (primefaces 3.4.1) have binding attribute

```
<p:outputPanel layout="block" autoUpdate="true" binding="#{bean.outputPanel}"/>
```

In the bean htmlInputText created dynamically and attached with outputpanel

Outputpanel Getter method

```
private OutputPanel outputPanel=new OutputPanel();

public final OutputPanel getOutputPanel() {
        outputPanel = (OutputPanel) app
                .createComponent(OutputPanel.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        return outputPanel;
    }
```

htmlInputText Binding

```
outputPanel.getChildren().add(new HTMLInputText());
```

This generates a inputtext perfectly but after creating a inputtext if I refresh the page its getting disappeared.
Even for an ajax request if I update the outputpanel components getting disappeared.

Comment: Why do you need to create components dynamically?

Comment: i am creating gui editor like dotnet, while drag and drop i need to create components dynamically

Comment: If I were you, I would use plain HTML instead of creating JSF components on the fly.

Comment: plain html how you render on jsf page according to my company jsf our framework but i am allowed to use html components(on the fly only) but the page should be .xhtml

Comment: You can use plain HTML on Facelets i.e. `<div>`. Note that you can use  plain HTML to help building your site. If you really *need* to use JSF, then you can use `jsfc` attribute as shown here: [Should I use Facelets “jsfc” attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2337908/1065197). Still, I don't think JSF is the technology for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the help but using jsfc i can render a html component as a jsf component is that right in that case i am actually rendering jsf components thats not the problem but why its getting disappeared

Comment: As I've said at the end of my last comment, I don't think JSF is the right technology for the task at hand. Note that there is no silver bullet technology that will work on everything you think it could. By the way, in the end you will only have a giant String of HTML (and possibly CSS) code that you can easily render using `<h:outputText escape="false">`.

Comment: thanks  Luiggi Mendoza <h:outputText escape="false"> i tried when i was start the project. Any way thanks for your help friend.

Comment: can you suggest some technologies to obtain this task

Comment: AFAIK, JavaScript/jQuery.