# JSP & JSF integration

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsf-2

Is it possible that I just don't use facelete tags inside my JSP and I connect my UI to my controller JSF ManagedBean annotation ?

maybe you ask me why do I need to do this ? 
I have a static page and I have to make it as a UI for a project and when I was making the JSF page I noticed that JSF html tag for example doesn't have styleClass for radio input element ...

I don't have any permission to use javascript and change the content of the page ...

if you have any link or tutorial for this issues or JSP and ManagedBean integration example without using facelete tag please give me.

thanx in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

1. From the documentation, there is a style & styleClass attribute defined for [selectOneRadio](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneRadio.html).
2. Then there is also the [jsfc attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337908/should-i-use-facelets-jsfc-attribute) that can help translate your html page in to a JSF page. This might be something that you are looking for.

Hope that helps

Comment: what I'm looking for are the selectItem elements here is my html code:      <input type="radio" class="right price" name="price" id="1-price" value="1000" />
        <label class="right radio-label" for="1-price"><span></span>1000</label>  when I'm turning this into JSF I can't put style for <f:selectItem  ...>

Comment: Can you create a custom component / or a custom renderer?